# Showing Context Menu on right click of High Chart series

Tags: highcharts

I want to show a context menu on right click of the series plotted in High charts. I am not able to find any option in High charts to do this. Can any one suggest a way to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Well it is 2019 and there still isn't a solution for this that comes with the base `HighCharts` download. I have found a way to manipulate the *LEFT* click, in order to show a menu of sorts. Now I understand this may not be the best case scenario, but you still have full access to all of the data from the click, and will still be able to do normal drill down functionality etc. You just might have to rework it. This is a `TypeScript` example, but can easily be replicated to `JavaScript` with a few edits.

Please excuse the lack of `CSS` for the menu.

Your functions initialized before the chart. The variable is used to keep the menu from disappearing and is ***NOT*** mandatory here.

```js
let callDrillDown = () => {
    alert('drill1');
}

let callDrillDown2 = () => {
    alert('drill2');
}

let mouseIn: boolean;
```

This is the bread and butter, during the click, you're pulling the `<div>` from the `HTML` and adding an `onclick` action to it.

```js
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        events: {
            click: (event: any) => {
                let contextMenu = document.getElementById('contextMenu');
                let contextMenuItem1 = document.getElementById('contextMenuItem1');
                let contextMenuItem2 = document.getElementById('contextMenuItem2');

                contextMenuItem1.onclick = callDrillDown;
                contextMenuItem2.onclick = callDrillDown2;

                contextMenu.onmouseenter = () => {
                    mouseIn = true;
                };

                contextMenu.onmouseleave = () => {
                    mouseIn = false;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if (!mouseIn) {
                            contextMenu.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                };

                contextMenu.setAttribute('style', 'top: ' 
                       + event.pageY + 'px; left:'
                       + event.pageX + 'px;');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of the body add the `HTML`

```html
<div id="contextMenu" style="display: none" class="contextMenu">
    <div id="contextMenuItem1">Data</div>
    <div id="contextMenuItem2">Data2</div>
</div>
```

Here is the <kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0jm1usf/36/)</kbd>. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer on our Highcharts Forum. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I did the solution below. Hope it helps.

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                     contextmenu: function (e) {
                            $('#constext-menu-div').css({top: e.chartY, left: e.chartX});
                            $('#constext-menu-div').show();
                            console.log(e);
                        },
                        click: function(){
                            $('#constext-menu-div').hide();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

"http://jsfiddle.net/c42Ms/45/"

Comment: doesn't in fiddle for me in chrome.

Comment: Check inside console of dev-tool, this fiddle gives an error. If you comment HighchartsAdapter.fireEvent() method from the code and run again, the context menu shows up properly.

Comment: Yep, no workii.

Answer (score 0):

It is not built-in functionality, but you can use [custom-events](https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extention and then catch right click. Last step will be show/hide any div with menu.

Comment: Your plugin uses `jQuery`... I would not suggest implementing a massive library for a right click. There has to be other ways for this.